# Importação de código em react native windows para Mac

Tags: mobile, react, react-native

Estou com uma dúvida com *React* native.
Se eu desenvolver no ambiente *Windows*, como passo esse código no *Mac* para distribuir o projeto para *Android* e *IOS*?

Comment: Melhor estudar novamente a respeito de react-native, afinal, ele não é híbrido. 
Sobre a dúvida, para o IOS você até pode desenvolver em ambiente windows/linux, porém, para compilar e gerar o executável deverá ser em um ambiente MAC.

Você abre o projeto no XCode, configura e compila. Da mesma forma que é em ambiente Windows/Linux

Comment: Vale ressaltar que caso esteja desenvolvendo usando o expo do react native você pode compilar para IOS sem estar em um mac sim, caso o contrario segue oque o @SergioClemente falou, você terá que usar um mac para buildar a aplicação IOS e uma observação que o sergio também citou, React native não é hibrido

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pelas informações me ajudou bastante, sobre ser hibrido eu deduzi por conta de ser um código apenas para os 2 dispositivos mobile. Vou estudar mais com certeza.